# Reading file from other class

Tags: java, io, filenotfoundexception

For the assignment, I created text files

and defined main class for the test

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File input1 = new File("inputFile1.txt");
    File input2 = new File("inputFile2.txt");

    CalcCheck file1 = new CalcCheck(input1);
    CalcCheck file2 = new CalcCheck(input2);

    file1.CheckStart();
}
```

After I defined main class,

I defined other class

```
private File checkingFile;

CalcCheck (File files)
{
    checkingFile = files;
}

void CheckStart()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (checkingFile);
    System.out.println("checking start");
    checkFileNull();
} ...
```

`However, the Scanner sc = new Scanner (checkingFile)` throws

> FileNotFoundException

.

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: It says `FileNotFoundException` and it is obvious.

Comment: You're using a relative file path, and the error message is telling you that the file is not there.  You could try using an absolute path, e.g. `C:\\path\\to\\inputFile1.txt`.

Comment: Do you actually have a file named "inputFile1.txt" and "inputFile2.txt" at the same package location of your class file?

Comment: Where are these two files actually located?

Comment: @Xu Lei yes I put those class and txt file in the same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of Scan throws FileNotFoundException. This is actually a checked exception and you need to either surround the code with try ... catch ...

For example:

```
void CheckStart()
{
    Scanner sc;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner (checkingFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("checking start");
    checkFileNull();
}
```

Or you need to declare the exception in the method that calls the constructor. 
For example:

```
void CheckStart() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (checkingFile);
    System.out.println("checking start");
    checkFileNull();
}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation) for more information.